# Calling another shell script with bash and specifying input

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to call another shell script with bash, however this script doesn't accept any command line arguments. Instead, it runs, checks a few things, and then prompts the user for input like this:

```
Checking....done
Please enter ID #: (user input here)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `read` command?

Comment: Sort of the reverse. The script I'm trying to call is using the read command to take the user input and processing it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
echo "My id" | ./script
Checking... done
Please enter ID: My id
```

or

```
./script << EOF
My_id
another input
EOF

Checking... done
Please enter ID: My_id
<blah>
Please enter something: anoter input
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `expect`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn php /path/to/script
expect "ID #: "
send "{ID#}\r"
interact
```

Reference: [Simulate user input in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670716/simulate-user-input-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you have single input to feed then echo is enough like,

echo "input" | ./script.sh

if you have more than 1 input then expect is good and only option,

record a script as mentioned above and then run it

expect sampleexpect.expec