# Is there a way to automate installing new releases on a GitHub Server

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

Ok so the task I am attempting to accomplish is this.  I am part of a team that manages a github server for a large company.  My boss has asked me to do some research and find out if there is a way to automate the installation of new releases of GitHub Enterprise.

I am aware that the Enterprise application can check for, and download, new releases.

What I want to know is if there is a way, some sort of script, or anything else, that will enable my team to not have to manually run an installation of the new releases.

Comment: How often are you installing these releases?

Comment: The idea would be to have it be automatically installed as soon as a release comes out

Comment: Yes it should be possible. It will depend on how you set up your servers - e.g. HA and backups.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 21, June 2016**

Based on a new feature added recently to Github Enterprise. I'm updating this answer in case it helps other peeps in future

Github Enterprise 2.6.4 release notes mentions

> - Prompt-less upgrades can now be performed by passing the -y argument to ghe-upgrade

So basically you don't need to do simulate user input anymore. I've added this to the answer below

---

Not sure if there's an existing script but you could just create your own

- Run `ghe-update-check` on the server
- Parse the result from the `/var/lib/ghe-updates/ghe-update-check.status`
- After this you basically execute the scripts mentioned in the [upgrade docs](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.6/admin/guides/installation/upgrading-the-github-enterprise-virtual-machine/)
- Add checks if you just want minor releases to be upgraded automatically
- If an update exists then just download it `curl -L -O https://github-enterprise.s3.amazonaws.com/ami/updates/<package-name>.pkg`
- Might be a good idea to enable maintenance mode before starting the upgrade `ghe-maintenance -s`
- Run `ghe-upgrade -y <package-name>.pkg` (The -y option is a prompt-less upgrade. Only available in newer versions 2.6.4+ however)
- Once it restarts after the upgrade disable maintenance mode `ghe-maintenance -u`
- Put the whole script in a cron job to check for updates as often as you want

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward when you put it that way.  What about the response part when you have to type y or n?

Comment: hmm since ghe-upgrade doesn't have a silent mode you might have to use expect to simulate user input it seems quite straightforward http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670716/simulate-user-input-in-bash-script