# automatically enter password in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to access HP switch from redhat 7 and need a way to enter the password automatically.

```
[root@backup ]# ssh root@192.168.0.19
root@192.168.0.19's password:
```

Comment: You don't need a way to enter the password. Use authentication with public keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide password to a command that prompts for one in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4857702/608639), [Is there a way to input automatically when running a shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9075478/608639), [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3980668/608639), [Simulate user input in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14670716/608639), etc.