# automate responses on command prompt

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

Is there any way to automate the installation of this software using shell script?
The problem is that I have to press ENTER and type YES twice and I am not sure how to use these 4 steps.

```
wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/4.8.3-4/Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh

bash Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

When I run the command mentioned above, I have these 4 steps:

```
 press ENTER
 type YES
 press ENTER
 type YES
```

I want to add this installation as a shell script in docker file or (if possible) directly in dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
chmod +x Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh
./Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh -b
```

(batch mode).

Check:

```
./Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh -h
```

> `-b`           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention), it is expected the license terms are agreed upon

Answer (score 0):

You could use the functions expect & send from the package expect.

[Man Page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)
Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14670734/4801311)

Comment: True esp. on Ubuntu it adds a lot of other packages to the system (up to 150+ MB; on Arch it was ~3MB due to depending on Tcl and 300kB for the package itself). Just thought it might be helpful in case there are other dependencies requiring interaction, not having a batch mode.

Comment: This is not a solution as-is, should belongs to a comment